# What is the process for using data in various projections with the ESRI JS API v4.8?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

We have an extensive collection of GIS data sitting in ArcSDE, exposed via map and feature services, and already in a regional (projected) coordinate system. We are starting to explore building web applications using HTML 5 and JavaScript, including ArcGIS API for Javascript 4.8.

If we use an ESRI basemap (e,g, streets, satellite, hybrid, topo, gray, dark-gray, oceans, osm, national-geographic), found in the `Map` object > `basemap` property, what is the process for incorporating our feature services in SRID 'xyz' with a basemap in SRID 'abc'? What if we include multiple feature services from various federal, state and local agencies with, potentially, different SRIDs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case in a project.
I've added without problems a feature service with a different SRID on Esri's OpenStreetMap basemap.

But when i couldn't retrieve geometries using the module Query, *until* I added this Query parameter : `query.outSpatialReference = view.spatialReference;`